# onClick method not working with rb.velocity in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a brick breaker clone where i shoot a ball in the direction determined by another object when a button is clicked. I added a Debug.Log to confirm that the button and function are working and they do... The movement code also works when in the start function. It does not work in The ShootBall() function.

```
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    
}
public void ShootBall()
{
    Debug.Log("pressed");
    rb.velocity = (transform.up * moveSpeed);
}
```

Comment: BTW, `unityscript` is [no longer](https://blog.unity.com/community/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset) a thing and yours is `C#` not the former

Comment: How are you determining onclick?

Comment: im using a button with an onClick function linked to the shootball function. I confirmed that it works by adding a debug.log when the button is clicked. The movement code does not work though...

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup it like this:

1. Add OnClick function to the button then drug and drop there your GameObject
2. Choose your script name and method in the list
   [->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulfZd.png)